# Gulp clean task being called from other tasks

Tags: gulp, gulp-4

```
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('css')),
    gulp.watch(['./app/scss/**/*.scss'], gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('css')))
);
```

When using any other task in my gulpfile for some reason gulp.watch is being called. Does anyone know what is going wrong with this task?

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('css')), () => {
      gulp.watch(['./app/scss/**/*.scss'], gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('css')))
    }
);
```

It appears the issue is calling the gulp.watch function directly rather than from inside of a function. The above code fixes the issue.